# Enable only Click event inside mouseup event Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have `ul` tag inside `div` tag. I have applied `mouseup` event on `div` tag and `click` event on `ul` tag.

**Issue**
Whenever I click `ul` tag, then both `mouseup` and `click` events are triggered.

What I want is that when I click on `ul` tag, then only `click` event should trigger and if I do `mouseup` event on `div` tag, then only `mouseup` event should trigger.

My code:
HTML:

```
<div class="m1">
    Nitin Solanki
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '.m1', function(){
    alert('div mouseup ');
});

$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
    alert("ul li- clicked");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/iNikkzz/e2fzkj6c/5/)

Comment: post your code in the question... not just a fiddle link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the propagation of the event

```js
$(document).on('mouseup', '.m1', function() {
  alert('div mouseup ');
});
$(document).on('mouseup', '.m1 ul', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
});


$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
  alert("ul li- clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1">
  Nitin Solanki
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check if the clicked element is a div or a list:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '.m1', function(event){
    // Check if the clicked element is the div and not the list
    if($(event.target).is('div'))
        alert('div mouseup ');
});

$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
    alert("ul li- clicked ");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is event bubbling. You can handle this using `event.stopPropagation();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("ul li").click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            alert("The ul li element was clicked.");
        });

        $(".m1").click(function(){
            alert("The div element was clicked.");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange question, as part of a "click" is actually a mouseup.
A click comprises of a mousedown followed by a mouseup on the same element.

The only thing I think you could do here is to store when a click has started, and add a onesecond timeout to a variable that the mouseup event depends on.

Like this.  (I feel dirty even posting this).

```
var clickStarted = false;

$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
    alert("ul li- clicked");
    clickStarted = false;
});

$(document).on('mousedown', 'ul li', function(){
    clickStarted = true;
    setTimeout(function(){ clickStarted = false; }, 1000);    
});

$(document).on('mouseup', '.m1', function(){
    if(!clickStarted)
        alert('div mouseup ');
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iNikkzz/e2fzkj6c/5/)